# Laravel Eloquent ORM: Change model so left join is *always* performed

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a very simple Eloquent Model:

```
class HelpdeskComment extends Model
{
    protected $table   = 'helpdesk_comment';
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'helpdesk_topic_id'];

    public function topic () {
        return $this->belongsTo ('\\App\\Model\\HelpdeskTopic');
    }

    public function user () {
        return $this->belongsTo ('\\App\\Model\\User');
    }
}
```

This all works quite well when doing stuff like

```
$user = $helpdeskComment->user;
```

However, I would like to change the model so that the User table (specifically the "username" field) is *always* left-joined against the HelpdeskComment table, regardless of the query function called. Is there a simple/central way to achieve this or do I have to override each function (all(), etc.)?

Thanks for any ideas & pointers.

Comment: Whilst I don't have a specific answer for you - I'm curious as to why you would want to do this? Seems like breaking modular functionality to me.
An option would be to, rather than override functions, build a helper/interface for it and use that for calls instead.

Comment: Maybe you're pointing me into a better direction here. The reason I want to do this is that I want to display the username from the template engine (Twig in this case) and so far I've been unable to figure out how to make twig retrieve the username.

Comment: You're passing data to the view somehow - why not just pass the exact data that you want to display? If you need multiple pieces of information from the `$user` object - then prepare it into something that Twig can work with (although I'm sure it can fetch from objects somehow) and send *that* to the view? :)

Quoting the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html):
`You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable (methods or properties of a PHP object, or items of a PHP array)`

Perhaps `{{ user.name }` would work as a direct reference to the object?